# In angular-meteor, document obtained with $meteor.object does not render

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I have an angular-meteor program in which the `$meteor.object` method returns a weird object instead of a document.

I am writing code very similar to the angluar-meteor turorial (http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_06):

scratch.js:

```
angular.module("docflow").controller("ScratchCtrl", 
    ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$stateParams", "$meteor",
    function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $meteor){
        $scope.bookId = $stateParams.bookId;
        $scope.book = $meteor.object(Books, $scope.bookId);
    }]);
```

scratch.ng.html:

```
<div>           
    Id: {{ bookId }}<br/>
    Name: {{ book.name }}<br/>
    Book: {{ book|json }}
</div>
```

This is what gets rendered -- note there is nothing after Name:

Id: dMk7PuQzrPCtwznNC

Name:

Book: { "autorunComputation": { "stopped": false, "invalidated": false, "firstRun": false, "_id": 25, "_onInvalidateCallbacks": [ null, null ], "_parent": null, "_recomputing": false } }

---

I know the book object exists and has a name attribute. If I directly query mongo with the rendered id I get the expected object:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.books.findOne({_id: "dMk7PuQzrPCtwznNC"});
{ "_id" : "dMk7PuQzrPCtwznNC", "name" : "A", "owner" : "Y5zQY4KeD9BSHdDma" }
```

Why isn't the name of the Book rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems writing the question down helped... So the problem is I removed the `autopublish` package, and I did not subscribe to the collection. This line:

```
$scope.book = $meteor.object(Books, $scope.bookId);
```

Must be changed to

```
$scope.book = $meteor.object(Books, $scope.bookId).subscribe("books");
```